# MySQL Join over multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I am trying to achieve dynamic META information so that it will allow META information to be inserted depending on the page that you are viewing.

I Have 3 tables

```
CATEGORIES
  category_id,
  category_name,
  category_title,
  category_url,
  site_id,

SITE
  site_id,
  site_name,
  site_url,
  meta_kw,
  meta_desc,

CATEGORY_META
  site_id,
  category_id,
  meta_keywords,
  meta_description,
```

I am trying to run a query that allows for the population of the META information from the SITE table if no information exists inside the CATEGORY_META table.  To achieve this I am looking at the "category_url" that exists and gleaning the "category_id" from that to run a subquery.  However it is returning an empty row which I do not want and is causing errors.

My Query looks like this:

```
SELECT category_id, s.meta_kw, s.meta_desc, m.meta_keywords, m.meta_description
FROM cms_sites s
LEFT JOIN cms_category_meta m
ON s.site_id=m.site_id AND m.category_id = 
(SELECT category_id FROM cms_categories WHERE category_url='?')
```

which returns:

```
 |category_id  |meta_kw  |meta_Desc | meta_keywords  |meta_description  |
 |NULL         |kw       |desc      |NULL            |NULL              |
 |NULL         |         |          |NULL            |NULL              |
```

I am relatively new to MySQL and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably have one "empty" row on `cms_sites`.

Comment: Yup, thats got it, I added a secondary WHERE clause to find sites with an ID of 1 and it solved the issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  category_id, s.meta_kw, s.meta_desc, m.meta_keywords, m.meta_description
FROM cms_sites s 
LEFT JOIN cms_category_meta m ON s.site_id = m.site_id 
LEFT JOIN cms_categories cat ON m.category_id = cat.category_id
                            AND cat.category_url = '?'
```

Anyway, if you have some "empty" row as @jlcd told you, this won't solve you problem.